# How to parse XML in a Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, webservice-client

Could someone tell me how to parse a XML-String that i receive from a wcf-rest service?

my webserive XML-String looks like

```
<WS>
    <Info>
        <Name>Beta</Name>
        <Description>Prototyps</Description>
    </Info>
    <Pages>
        <Page>
            <Name>Custom</Name>
            <Description>toDo</Description>
        </Page>
        ...many other pages...
    </Pages>
 </WS>
```

an my phone sourcecode:

```
public void DownloadCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        var answer = XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("WS"); // null
        ...
    }
}
```

if i try to parse it through XDocument.Load(e.Result) then i get the exception: File not Found.

i just want the "unique" information of the Info-Node and a list of all Page-Nodes with their values

**Update**
Even if i try to load the Root-Element via var item = xdoc.Root.Descendants(); item will be assigned to the whole xml-file.

**Update 2** it seems the problem occurs with the namespaces in the root-element. with namespaces xdocument will parse the webservice output not correctly. if i delete the namespaces it works fine. could someone explain me this issue? and is there a handy solution for deleting all namespaces?

**update 3** A Handy way for removing namespaces[1](http://bohu7.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/removing-default-namespaces-from-an-xdocument/)

Comment: I don't really dabble in WCF, but I'm pretty sure there are easier ways to consumer WCF services.

Comment: im sorry it could be another restful service that is not implemented with wcf. for a general case it would probably better to parse it manualy, isn`t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With really simple XML if you know the format wont change, you might be interested in using XPath:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var name = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("/WS/Info/Name");
```

but for the multiple pages, maybe some linq to xml

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var pages = xdoc.Descendants("Pages").Single();
var PagesList = pages.Elements().Select(x => new Page((string)x.Element("Name"), (string)x.Element("Description"))).ToList();
```

Where Page is a simple class:

```
public class Page
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descrip { get; set; }
    public Page(string name, string descrip)
    {
        Name = name;
        Descrip = descrip;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Also to select the Info without XPath:

```
var info = xdoc.Descendants("Info").Single();
var InfoName = info.Element("Name").Value;
var InfoDescrip = info.Element("Description").Value;
```

Comment: thanks for your recommendation but XPathSelectElement is not available on WP7. If i try "var pages = xdoc.Descendants("pages").Single();" then i get "InvalidOperationException" - "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: @ViktorZimmermann Sorry, I didn't know about the XPath WP7 limitation.  Also, I had some small errors in my code, but I have edited with tested code that should work.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Viktor - [XDocument.Load(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) attempts to load an XDocument by the supplied filename, not a string representation of an XML element.

You say `var answer = XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("WS"); // null`, but which part is null?  The parsed XElement or the attempt to grab a descendant?  If `<WS>...</WS>` is your root element, would the `.Descendents("WS")` call return the root element?  Based on the documentation for [XElement.DescendantsAndSelf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300437.aspx), I'm guessing not.  Have you instead tried calling:

```
var answer = XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("Info");
```

A quick test on my end showed that, with WS as the root element, calling `XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("WS");` yielded no results, while `XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("Info");` yielded the `<Info>...</Info>` element.

Comment: Very true, I believe [XDocument.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) is what he was looking for.

Comment: your suggestion to XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("Info") works neither.  i cant grep any node of that xml-file, but if take a look in e.Result the expected "Xml-String" is present.

Comment: Viktor - that's interesting.  I took your XML snippet above, dropped it into a string, verbatim (aside from the ellipsis), and ran it through XElement.Parse(), yielding the resulting Info element.  Have you set breakpoints in your code to see what is coming out of the call to `.Descendants("Info")`?  Something else must be amiss.